# In IE, how can I non-repetitively specify the column numbers of a bunch of divs that differ only in column number?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, grid

Because IE is stupid, I'm finding myself needing to do the following:

```
    .myClass:nth-of-type(1){
      -ms-grid-column: 1;
    }
    .myClass:nth-of-type(2){
      -ms-grid-column: 2;
    }
    .myClass:nth-of-type(3){
      -ms-grid-column: 3;
    }
```

etc.

Is there a more elegant way? Something like:

```
    .myClass:nth-of-type(n){
      -ms-grid-column: n;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, You want to enter numbers in DIV?

If yes, Then you can try to loop through DIVs and then try to insert numbers in it.

Below is one example that you can try to refer.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 1; i < divs.length; i++){
   //do something to each div like
   divs[i].innerHTML = i;
}
```

You can modify the code as your requirement.